# Make portions of input value read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

If the value of my `input` is a date

```
03/22/2012
```

and I want the numbers to be editable but not the `/`, can I make that portion of the `input` read only?

I would like to be able to accomplish this without plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I might do something like this, using CSS only:

```
div#dateInput{
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:100px;
    margin:1em;
}

div#dateInput input{
    border:0;
    width:20px;
    outline:0;
}

div#dateInput input:nth-last-child(1){
    border:0;
    width:35px;
    outline:0;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dateInput">
    <input type="text" /> /
    <input type="text" /> /
    <input type="text" />
</div>​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6BG/

Basically, I am removing the border and the outline from three `input` fields and "hiding" those fields in a `div` that I style to look like one `input`.

Comment: I originally had it designed this way, but due to other architectural decisions I had to modify it to 1 input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can verify in a `onchange` handler if the `/` is removed and you can put it back, letting the impression that only the values between the `/` can be edited.

A second alternative would be to use 3 fields separated by `/`, but this is kind of an ugly solution, but probably the most implemented.

Comment: then all you have to do is to implement a simple handler that checks the value ( the first solution ). The good part is that when it will be sent you do not have to worry to mix the 3 value, plus in the handler you could test if the characters are numbers and if it is a valid date.